# Boot from USB option doesn't pop up

Tags: boot, usb

I just fully installed Ubuntu 17.04 on my HP Pavilion Notebook, as the only operating system running on it at the moment. I tested it out for a bit and now I want to go back to Windows 10 with Ubuntu running in a virtual machine.

I made a working, bootable USB drive with Windows 10 (I tested the USB drive on my desktop and it works, the option to boot from USB pops up), but the problem is that the option to boot up from USB doesn't pop up on the laptop.

I have the settings in BIOS done corectly, secure boot is disabled, legacy boot disabled and the order where to boot from is set with USB drive on top, but the option still doesn't pop up.

[BIOS settings picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcstx.jpg)

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: HP computers, particularly new ones, can be hard to boot from USB or hard to install into. Maybe your Windows install drive was made to work in BIOS mode alias legacy mode. Please tell us the model id and the year it was manufactured! Maybe someone, who has such a computer will read your question and be able to give advice. Did you try to get a temporary boot menu via a hotkey (in some HP computers it is F9, but it might be a different key in your computer).

Comment: This is the laptop model https://www.amazon.com/HP-Special-15-an050nr-15-6-Inch-Laptop/dp/B015W7OTGG/. I tried the temporary boot menu and it opened up this menu: http://i.imgur.com/noC20us.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first power it on and you hit F9 to select a boot device you don't see USB as an option? What do you see at that screen?

**EDIT**: Try switching on legacy boot and boot from USB then.

Comment: OS boot Manager (UEFI) - ubuntu <TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100> and Boot From EFI File

Comment: try switching on legacy boot and boot from USB then

Comment: Yeah, that did it. I partitioned my USB drive in MBR so I had to enable legacy boot and then set the boot order for legacy booting. After doing this, the USB drive appeared when going into the temporary boot menu (F9).